# Python - wikipedia Page Error exception handling to get the recommended pages

Tags: python, wikipedia

is it possible to get the recommended pages while handling wikipedia PageError exception? There is an "options" property in the case of DisambiguationError. Is there any such thing for PageError?

for DisambiguationError we do the following:

```
import wikipedia
try:
    page = wikipedia.page("Recommendation")
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
    print e.options
```

can we do anthing similar for PageError exception to get the list of pages? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, [wikipedia.exceptions.PageError is raised when no Wikipedia matched a query](http://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#module-wikipedia.exceptions)

```
    import wikipedia
    try:
      page = wikipedia.page("asdsadsadsad")
    except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
      print e.options
    except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError as e:
      print e
```

Page id "asdsadsadsad" does not match any pages. Try another id!

Answer (score 1):

The `wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError` class does not have an `option` attribute. For simply printing information, you can try one of following:

```
import wikipedia
try:
    page = wikipedia.page("Recommendation")
except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError as e:
    print e
    print e.args
    print e.paeid
    print e.message
```